# Unable to run app in simulator

Tags: xcode, macos, ios8, ios-simulator, osx-yosemite

I have copied Xcode from another mac and pasted in applications folder but i got this error when i tried to run my app:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim is not owned by root
```

However, I resolved this error by writing code below in terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

But because of above code I got stuck with another error related to simulator:

An error was encountered while running
**(Domain = com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, Code = 146)**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just copying and pasting will not install all the required material that xocde needs to run everything correctly

Answer (score 1):

You haven't installed Xcode properly.

Comment: i copied from another mac and just pasted there

Comment: @warzone_fz That's not how it should be installed.

Comment: And when Apple's idiot installer decides to install XCode in the wrong place, like on top of XCode5 on a non-system disk instead of in the current application folder?

Answer (score 0):

copy your xcode on application folder then try this on terminal:

```
sudo chown root /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim
```